# Apache Camel support for AWS Elastic Transcoder

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-camel, amazon-elastic-transcoder

Does anybody know about a component that allows issuing transcoding requests with apache Camel? I looked at the camel-aws package in GIT and it does not look like it is even work in progress.

Before I start to hck my own, I just wanted to validate that there is nothing out there that I might be missing.

Answer (score 1):

I have been taking a look around internet and the [Apache Camel JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL) and it does not seem to be any development related to that. I would suggest that if you are planning to create your own, use any of the other available ones as example (there are already many things about keys and amazon stuff already built) and then contribute the code.